# Stop enemy tilting upwards if it is close to the player. Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

How can I stop the rotation of the enemies x and z axis, so that the enemy only turns left and right like a normal video game enemy?
I hope my question is clear. Thank you.

Code from "How To Make A Survival Horror Game"

```
void Update()
{
    transform.LookAt(thePlayer.transform);
    if (attackTrigger == false)
    {
        enemySpeed = 0.01f;
        theEnemy.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Z_Run_InPlace 1");
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, thePlayer.transform.position, enemySpeed);
    }

    if (attackTrigger == true && isAttacking == false)
    {
        enemySpeed = 0;
        theEnemy.GetComponent<Animation>().Play("Z_Attack 2");
        StartCoroutine(InflictDamage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your enemy contrained to X to Z only try making this.

```
transform.LookAt(new Vector3(thePlayer.tranform.position.x,0,thePlayer.tranform.position.z));
```

and also this one if moving.

```
transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, new Vector3(thePlayer.tranform.position.x,0,thePlayer.tranform.position.z), enemySpeed);
```

Comment: the MoveTowards also?

Comment: I think it seems fine now.